# Access item defined in parent in Angular 4 + bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I have defined a modal window (as an ng-templated named #copyrightpopup) in the parent layer, and in a child layer I have a link that should open that modal window as follows:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#" (click)="open(window.opener.angular.element('#copyrightpopup'))">
    <img src="assets/images/logo_name.png">
</a>
```

but clicking the link causes error "cannot read property opener of undefined".

I'm assembly this code by cutting and pasting examples so I suspect I'm not accessing the parent correctly.  I've tried variations but can't figure out how to access an object by in the parent.